# using inserted media as background of a div in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to create a custom theme, where in one is supposed to use some custom post types in which he is supposed to insert one new media (Image) and then i have to use that attached image as the background of some div inside my post ? How do i make best use of wordpress in this scenario. 
What currently i am doing is -

```
<div class="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $bgImageClass, true); ?>"></div>
```

And then i am defining this image class in my style sheet and uploading media seperately , 
Now i did google it up to find some nice solution and what i found till now is

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id );
```

and explicitly giving attachment ID which i dont prefer, since d/w will have to work again. Now i read about the function -

```
 <?php get_attached_media( $type, $post_id ) ?>
```

But i am not sure about its usage, i dont understand what and how it will return the media.
So, how can i use the power of wordpress in this scenario?

Comment: Why don't you use post thumbnails otherwise known as "featured image"? You can read more at https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails.

Comment: yeah, I can use that but again I dont want the whole post's background to be that image but only a part of it a div inside a div , so how do I do that?